# Cant we pass object to write function to add data in one file to another file in python?

Tags: python, file

This is the code I tried

```
f=open("my","r")
j=open("allot","w")
j.write(f)
j=open("allot","r")
print(j.read())
```

In the above code why cannot we pass f object as a parameter to write function in line 3?

Comment: You should pass the content of the file object like this `j.write(f.read())`

Answer (score 0):

`.write` method of file object takes string type variable only as arguments. Passing it another file object will not work.

```
f=open("my","r")
j=open("allot","w")
j.write(f.read())
j.close()
j=open("allot","r")
print(j.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to call `close()` on the file objects after opening files.

Using `with` statement manages this for you by automatically closing them once the block is exited.

```py
with open("my","r") as f, open("allot", "w") as j:
        j.write(f.read())

with open("allot", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```